# Unknown CREATE TABLE syntax error near 'unsigned int ..'

Tags: mysql, create-table

I've been staring at this simple `CREATE TABLE` query for 20 minutes, and I can't figure out why it's throwing an error:

```
create table `schema_change` (
    `schema_change_id` unsigned int not null auto_increment,
    `major_release_number` unsigned int not null,
    `minor_release_number` unsigned int not null,
    `point_release_number` unsigned int not null,
    `script_name` varchar(100) not null,
    `date_applied` datetime not null,
    constraint `pk_schema_change` primary key (
        `schema_change_id`
    )
);
```

The error returned is a basic syntax error, but I can't spot any syntax that's incorrect:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'unsigned int not null, minor_release_number unsigned int not
>   null, point_rel' at line 3

What am I missing?

(Using MySQL version 5.1.73)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNSIGNED` is a type attribute, and must come after the type name: `INT UNSIGNED`, not `UNSIGNED INT`.

Comment: Aha. Knew it would be something extremely simple. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You must use unsigned after the type, as it modifies the type of `int`

```
create table `schema_change` (
    `schema_change_id` int unsigned auto_increment,
    `major_release_number` int unsigned not null,
    `minor_release_number` int unsigned not null,
    `point_release_number`  int unsigned not null,
    `script_name` varchar(100) not null,
    `date_applied` datetime not null,
    constraint `pk_schema_change` primary key (
        `schema_change_id`
    )
);
```

See in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/685bf/1